# identical dicts giving error in test cases

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

DRF API response.data

```
respone.data = {'created': 1, 'status': 1}
```

and other data is from serializer.

```
MySerializer(user_obj, context={'request': self.request}).data
{'created': 1, 'status': 1}

self.assertEqual(d1,d2) gives difference. Apparently there is no difference but somehow both are not matching.
```

dump and again loads matches.

```
self.assertEqual(json.loads(json.dumps(d1)), json.loads(json.dumps(d2)))
```

sorted also matches.

```
self.assertEqual(sorted(response.data), sorted(data_))
```

Comment: *What* difference does it give? Could you paste the comparison?

Comment: Before doing the assertEqual, issue the following: `self.longMessage = True`, which will give you more details when `assertEqual` fails.

Comment: self.assertEqual(response.data, data_)
*** AssertionError: {'created': 1, 'status': 1} != {'created': 1, 'status': 1}

Answer (score 0):

DRF's Serializer `.data` method return an OrderedDict which is subclass of dict:

```
return OrderedDict([
            (field_name, field.get_value(self.initial_data))
             for field_name, field in self.fields.items()
             if (field.get_value(self.initial_data) is not empty) and
             not field.read_only
         ])
```

But you are creating a dict, which is different from [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: Both dict are of same type <class 'rest_framework.utils.serializer_helpers.ReturnDict'>

Comment: @MarkWaugh Okay, so now we know its a `ReturnDict` and not a `dict`. `ReturnDict` inherits from `OrderedDict` and items must have been added in the same order to be equal. You could do `dict(d1)==dict(d2)` to compare.